# A measure of how well my data matches a pattern

Tags: matlab, classification, curve-fitting, pattern-recognition

I have some data that they seem to follow a pattern and can be visually classified into three classes. This image shows two samples of each class:-

[image: This image]  It seems that:

```
First class: Five Gaussian functions can be fitted
Second class: Two Gaussian functions can be fitted
Third class: Non of the above.
```

Is there any measure that could say: for each sample, "how well 5 Gaussian functions can be fitted" and "how well 2 Gaussian functions can be fitted"? Then, I can use these measures to classify my data?

Please let me know if you think of a better solution for this problem.

Comment: This concerns the modality of statistical distributions. I suggest you try asking over at Cross-validated. I think you should look for "local minima". Google that plus whatever language you are using, e.g. MATLAB.

Comment: Have you considered trying to use a cross-correlation?

Comment: Do you always expect to see a summation of Gaussians with equal variance but different mean? Except for the "no correlation" of course.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71819381/how-to-measure-approximate-match-between-the-numpy-data-and-a-pattern-model-func

Answer (score 1):

The hard way would be the following:

- Fit a Mixture of Gaussians with both 5 and 2.
- Check the likelihood score of your data given each of the fitted Mixture of Gaussians.
- Is very likely 5 is always going to have a higher score than 2, if only because it allows for more points o high probability.
- Try to check whether the difference in scores is large enough to make you consider which one to pick.

Example:

If the score for 2 is 0.8 and the sore for 5 is 0.81, there was very little gain between changing models, thus, you can safely assume 2 is a better fit.

However, if the score for 2 is 0.2 and the score for 5 is 0.8, the gain was significant, which means that 5 is possibly a better fit.

Another way is to use 1D automatic clustering recognition techniques. Dirichlet Processes come to mind.